# Генератор списка списков и сложение i+j элементов

Tags: python, list, матрицы

У меня есть код, который генерирует список списков:

```
    n =  [[(i/j) for j in range   (1,5)] for i in range (1,5)]
```

Вывод:

```
    [[1.0, 0,5, 0.33333333333, 0,25],
    [2.0, 1.0, 0.66666666666, 0.5],
    [3.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.75],
    [4.0, 2.0, 1.33333333333, 1.0]]
```

Как итерировать этот список списков с помощью генератора, чтобы если i+j четное, то возвращаем число без изменений, если нет, то с минусом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

воспользуйтесь тернарным оператором:

```
n =  [[i/j if (i+j) % 2 == 0 else -i/j
       for j in range   (1,5)] 
      for i in range (1,5)]
```

результат:

```
In [285]: n
Out[285]:
[[1.0, -0.5, 0.3333333333333333, -0.25],
 [-2.0, 1.0, -0.6666666666666666, 0.5],
 [3.0, -1.5, 1.0, -0.75],
 [-4.0, 2.0, -1.3333333333333333, 1.0]]
```